# Python Circular Import error when using class based constructor injection

Tags: python, python-3.x

We have a code base where we initialize classes in Python using Constructor

so the folder structure is something like

```
a_module
 --> __init__.py
 --> a_service.py
 --> a_dao.py
 --> a_controller.py
b_module
 --> __init__.py
 --> b_service.py
 --> b_dao.py
 --> b_controller.py
c_module
 --> __init__.py
 --> c_service.py
 --> c_dao.py
 --> c_controller.py
```

and so on
`a_service.py` has

```
from ..b_module import BDao
from ..c_module import CDao
class AService
    def __init__(
        self,
        b_dao: BDao,
        c_dao: CDao,
,
    ):
        self._b_dao = b_dao
        self._c_dao = c_dao
```

the `__init__.py` inside a_module looks something like

```
from ..b_module import b_dao_object
from ..c_module import c_dao_object
a_service_obj = AClass(b_dao_obj,c_dao_obj)
```

The project is huge. the `__init__.py` file in each folder acts as a Dependency injector. But recently when CService also requires ADao or AService as dependency, we get a circular import error and we need to then use local imports inside function. But that makes that part of code tightly coupled and less testable, (can't stub the dependency)

example
say inside `c_service.py`

```
class CService:
    # Unable to initialize like below
    def __init__(
        self,
        a_service: AService, 
    
    ):
        self._a_service = a_service 
    ....
        
    # Instead have to do something like this
    def some_method(self):
       from ..a_module import a_service_obj #function local import :(
       a_service_obj.do_something()
```

So, what is the best practise, should we use a Dependency injection framework instead. Or is there any other way to avoid circular dependency.